# Find count of consecutive repeating element in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
A.    B.    C.     D
3.    4.    12     15
3.    5.     11.    2
3.    4.     1.      3
5.    4.     1.      4
```

I want count of consecutive repeating element.

Like

```
Column A
Element 3 = 3 times
Element 5 = 1 times

Column B
Element 4 = 2 times
```

Means I want only count of elements that are repeating consecutively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update

```
from itertools import groupby
d = {i:{k: len(list(v)) for k, v in groupby(j)} for i,j in zip(df.columns,df.values.T.tolist())}

d
Out[196]: 
{'A': {3: 3, 5: 1},
 'B': {4: 2, 5: 1},
 'C': {1: 2, 11: 1, 12: 1},
 'D': {2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 15: 1}}
```

`pandas` method

```
s=df.melt()
s['key']=s.groupby('variable').value.apply(lambda x : x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())

s.groupby(['variable','key','value']).value.count()
Out[202]: 
variable  key  value
A         1    3        3
          2    5        1
B         1    4        1
          2    5        1
          3    4        2
C         1    12       1
          2    11       1
          3    1        2
D         1    15       1
          2    2        1
          3    3        1
          4    4        1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: No, I want to count how many times each element comes in my column consecutively

Answer (score 0):

To get for column A ,

```
    value = my_frame["A"]
    for i in range(0,len(value)-1):
        if(value[i] == value[i+1]):        
            if value[i] not in my_dic:            
                my_dic[value[i]] = 1
            else:
                my_dic[value[i]] += 1
    else:
        for key,val in my_dic.items():
            print("Element " key," = ",val, " times ")
```

Similarly, you can use for other columns.